# AutoIncrement в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, entity-framework-core

Использовал раньше для работы с БД sql команды. Потихоньку перехожу на EF.
Раньше, я просто пропускал поле id при добавлении строки и БД сама создавала следующий id. Теперь, поле id оставлять пустым нельзя, а если использовать
`[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`,
то id генерируется какой-то рандомный.
Во первых, не попадет ли он таким образом в уже существующий, во вторых, я хочу чтобы мои id продолжали идти по порядку, так, как это происходит с sql командами. Как это сделать?

И сразу добавлю еще вопрос. После добавления новой строки, мне нужно сразу получить ее id, раньше для этого я отправлял sql запрос с max(id), но это костыль, как это сделать по человечески?

```
var bill = new Bill();
            
bill.user_id = Program.f1.user_id.ToString();
bill.shop_id = Program.f1.shop_id.ToString();
bill.client_id = client.id;
bill.total = sumToPay.ToString();
bill.discount = discount.ToString();
bill.date = MySql.DateTimeNow();

billContext.bills.Add(bill);
billContext.SaveChanges();
```

```
internal class Bill
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public string shop_id { get; set; }
    public string client_id { get; set; }
    public string total { get; set; }
    public string discount { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
}
```

```
CREATE TABLE `bills` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shop_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPDATE

Создаю класс для таблицы Ремонтов. В данной таблице есть много связей, и по связям как раз и вопрос. Конечно, перед тем как задавать вопрос, пытался его найти в гугле, но там описывают кейс создания связей используя CodeFirst. У меня же используются КривыеРукиFirst, так что ответ найти не вышло. Имеем:

```
public class Remont
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Column("status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [Column("client_id")]
        public int ClientId { get; set; }

        [Column("details")]
        public string Details { get; set; }

        [Column("user_id")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Column("price_sum")]
        public decimal PriceSum { get; set; }

        [Column("date_added")]
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        [Column("date_mod")]
        public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

        [Column("shop_id")]
        public int ShopId { get; set; }

        [Column("user_id_master")]
        public int MasterId { get; set; }

        [Column("deleted")]
        public int Deleted { get; set; }



        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext();
        public Client Client
        {
            get { return clientContext.clients.Where(n => n.id == ClientId).First(); }
            set { ClientId = Client.id; }
        }

        //public List<Remont_> RemontTovars { get; set; }

        //[ForeignKey("user_id")]
        //public User User { get; set; }

        //[ForeignKey("shop_id")]
        //public Shop Shop { get; set; }

        //[ForeignKey("user_id_master")]
        // User Master { get; set; }
    }
```

Проблема следующая, есть поле Client, которое должно содержать клиента, с id = ClientId. Как я понял, в CodeFirst эта связь создалась бы автоматом. Я попытался выйти из ситуации костылем

```
get { return clientContext.clients.Where(n => n.id == ClientId).First(); }
            set { ClientId = Client.id; }
```

Но это тоже не работает. Как это организовать по-человечески?

P.S. Закомментированные поля, так же нужно реализовать, думаю, у меня это выйдет по примеру с Клиентом. Возможно, вопросы будут только к списку.

P.P.S. Русский мною никогда не изучался и грамматика на интуитивном уровне. Так что не обессудьте.

Comment: у вас code-first? В сгенерированной схеме таблицы ключ тоже identity? Как понимать `То id генерируется какой - то рандомный.` - покажите конкретные данные и код добавления. `После добавления новой строки` - вы какой то объект добавляете, его id не обновился после добавления?

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/1.3.php

Comment: @tym32167
Дополнил вопрос. На последнем скрине видно строку, которая добавлена с использованием EF.

Comment: Смотрю на скрин, вижу идентификаторы идут по порядку. Где проблема?

Comment: @tym32167 Попытался добавить еще строк, два раза подряд вылезла ошибка, о дублировании первичного ключа, ЕФ попытался всунуть в запрос уже существующий ключ. Мне нужно, что б нумерация продолжалась, следующий id должен быть 235 и так дальше

Comment: Судя по картнке, следующий номер 38777. Можно точный текст ошибки и код добавления? Ошибка может произойти если айдишник руками заполняете

Comment: В DDL все колонки `*id` имеют тип `int`, а в c#-классе - тип `string`. Как это понимать?

Comment: Почему все свойства в классе сущности имеют тип `string`? / Какой подход используется: CodeFirst (явно нет), DatabaseFirst? Похоже вообще на _КривыеРукиFirst_.

Comment: Укажите используемую версию (номер) EF. Core или нет?

Comment: Если вы так заморачиваетесь, то вы не правильно представляете зачем нужен ID. Не важно как генерируется ID и в каком порядке, главное чтобы он был уникальный.

Comment: @tym32167 Говорю же, последняя строка, с большим значением была добавлена EF, и она как раз и является проблемой.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov действительно, id имеют тип стринг, потому что потом его использовать как строку удобнее. Как я понимаю, бд все равно возвращает все значения в виде строк.
Подход используется скорее DataBaseFirst. Ибо база данных была создана первой. Фактически, я просто создал класс для одной таблицы из бд (Bill) а так же (BillContext). И разбираюсь с EF. Со считыванием данных все мега удобно, куда удобнее запросов, но при записи данных, я сколкнулся с корявой генерацией id. Пытаюсь понять, как прийти к такому же варианту, что был, когда база сама создает СЛЕДУЮЩИЙ id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Раньше, я просто пропускал поле id при добавлении строки и БД сама создавала следующий id. Теперь, поле id оставлять пустым нельзя.

Свойство id можно оставлять пустым, если явно указано, что значение для него будет генерироваться в базе данных.

---

> После добавления новой строки, мне нужно сразу получить ее id

```
var bill = new Bill();
// ...
billContext.bills.Add(bill);
billContext.SaveChanges();

Console.WriteLine(bill.id); // здесь будет значение из БД
```

При выполнении этого кода провайдер EF Core сгенерирует SQL-запрос `INSERT` с последующим `SELECT` для получения ID.
После выполнения строки `billContext.SaveChanges();` экземпляр `bill` обретёт значение ID, полученное из базы.
Это при заданном атрибуте `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)`.

---

> раньше для этого я отправлял sql запрос с max(id), но это костыль, как это сделать по человечески?

Да, это костыль. В MySql для получения ID последней вставленной строки используется `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

---

> id генерируется какой-то рандомный

Значение генерируется в БД. БД ничего не знает, кто и как к ней обращается. Неважно, будет это SQL-запрос с помощью чистого ADO.NET, через micro-ORM наподобие Dapper, или с помощью LINQ-ORM типа Entity Framework. БД просто выдаст очередное значение - всё!

Почему на скриншоте такое большое различие между айдишниками? Скорее всего в промежутке между вставками этих строк были другие неудачные вставки, от которых отказались. Или строки были просто удалены.

Также нельзя исключать, что есть какие-то особенности СУБД MySql. Я не являюсь специалистом по ней. Но это сильно вряд ли.

А главное, вас не должны интересовать эти айдишники. Когда вы создаёте объект в C# (C++, Java, любом другом языке), вас же не заботит, по какому адресу в памяти он будет размещён? Точно так же не должно заботить, какой номер назначен строке в таблице БД.
Оставьте компьютеру ковыряться с циферками, он для этого предназначен. Человек должен заниматься творчеством!

---

Пройдёмся теперь по другим ошибкам.
В C# для именования свойств принят стиль PascalCase. Следовательно, класс должен выглядеть так:

```
internal class Bill
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("user_id")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Column("shop_id")]
    public int ShopId { get; set; }
    [Column("client_id")]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    [Column("total")]
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    [Column("discount")]
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    [Column("date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

В атрибуте `Column` задан маппинг для колонок таблицы в БД.

В комментариях вы пишете:

> Как я понимаю, бд все равно возвращает все значения в виде строк.

Это не так.
Вон же у вас в `CREATE TABLE` явно заданы типы колонкам: `int(11)`, `float`, `datetime`. Неужто эти типы затем не используются?

Ещё замечание. Судя по названиям: `total` и `discount` - в этих колонках хранятся денежные значения. Никогда не используйте для них вещественные типы! В БД для этого используйте `decimal(15,2)`, а в C# ему соответствует тип `decimal`.

---

Вы сперва создали базу данных с помощью DDL. А затем вручную написали классы сущностей для Entity Framework. Такой подход называется Database First.

Можно сгенерировать классы контекста и сущностей автоматически по уже существующей БД:
[Reverse Engineering](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)
[Creating a Model for an Existing Database in Entity Framework Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx)

Comment: 'В C# для именования свойств принят стиль CamelCase.' Наверное, имелся в виду PascalCase.

Comment: @aa_talanin - Спасибо! Исправил.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я так и не понял, почему БД решила продолжить нумерацию с такого значения, но в принципе, это действительно не проблема. Благодарен и за остальные замечания, по написанию кода. Со Scaffold-DbContext разобраться пока не удалось. Есть еще вопрос, что возник вот только что, при продолжении работы с EF, если вы не против, напишу его как UPDATE к этому вопросу, что б не расписывать заново контекст вопроса. Буду благодарен за ответ.

Comment: @NoMad - правило этого сайта: одна тема - один вопрос. Поэтому задайте новый вопрос отдельной темой. Краткий ответ: т. к. таблицы вы создаёте вручную, то и связи между ними тоже задайте вручную в момент создания.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Так и сделал.